# Import .txt file into MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I am trying to import a .txt file into MS Excel using the "Data" tab and "From Text/CVS".

I have uploaded both an image of the Excel import screen and another of a small part of my dataset. As you can see, when importing, the decimal point in the third column is not correct. How can i fix this?

[.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5HQw.jpg)

[Excel import screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqoGx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lays out how to enable the legacy import wizard, which supports more advanced configuration of imported data.

Open *File -> Options -> Data* and tick the checkbox *From Text (Legacy)* in the section *Show legacy data import wizards*.

Afterwards, in the *Data* ribbon, you will find the option *Get Data -> Legacy Wizards -> From Text (Legacy)*.

Select your delimiting options, proceed to the Advanced menu, and change the Column Type to your preferred decimal point (. as per your screenshot).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30458186